# Does Messaging Session end automatically?

Tags: service-cloud-console, servicecloud, sms, service-console

we've just set up SMS messaging with service cloud. Does anyone know if a messaging session will end automatically if it is inactive for a period of time? If so, how long of a timeframe and is there a way to configure it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you can end a Messaging session.

1. Ending it directly from the Messaging session when the conversation is over.
2. Messaging Sessions list view.

User must have 'End Messaging Session' permission check more details [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.livemessage_agent_end_session.htm&type=5).

Unfortunately, there is no way to end the session automatically. Kindly review [limitation](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gdm2dUAB/end-session-via-apex-code-or-process-builder).

Comment: Thanks for the input! So it sounds like Salesforce will never automatically end the session and it's up to the agent to do so.